# Can I use GetAsyncKeyState() outside of the main() function?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, keyboard, program-entry-point

I'm writing, just to get confidence with the programming procedures, a win32 application that responds to keyboard input. To do so I'm using the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function.

At first I wrote all my code in the `main()` function, and all seemed well, it worked. So I decided to complicate things, but that requires me to use the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function in a different function called by the `main()`. I thought I just needed to declare some variables outside the `main()` and move the code from the `main` to the new function like this:

```
int btnup_down = 0; 
int close = 1; 
int main(void){
    while (1){
        Sleep(50);
        listentokb();
        if (close == 0){
            break;
        }
    }return 0;
}
int listentokb(void){ 
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(0x4C) & 0x8000) && (ko == 0)){ 
        ko = 1; 
        printf("Ok you pressed k"); 
        return 0; 
    } else if (((GetAsyncKeyState(0x4C) == 0) && (ko == 1))  { 
        ko = 0; 
        printf("Now you released it"); 
        close = 0; 
        return 0; 
    }return 0; 
}
```

When I run this code, the loop keeps going and it doesn't matter if I press the key or not, it keeps looping without printf-ing anything. Any help will be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: You certainly don't need global variables for this. Also, 0x4C is the L key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to to with `main()` or not. You can call winapi function such as [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from wherever you want in your code, as long as you provide the good arrguments.

According to this list of [virtual key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the code 0x4c corresponds to the key <kbd>L</kbd> and not to the key <kbd>K</kbd>.  So after a bracket correction typo in your code, I could run it succesfully interupting the loop with <kbd>L</kbd>

**Some remarks about your function:**

Your function `listentokb()` always returns 0.  On the other hand, you use a global variable `close` to tell the calling function the result of your keyboard scanning.  This is a very bad practice:  whenever possible avoid global variables.

Here a slightly updated version of your code that bans global variables, and use return value to communicate the results:

```
const int KEY_K = 0x4B;    // avoid using values directly in the code

int listentokb (void){  // returns 'K' if K is released and 0 otherwise
    static int ko;      // this is like a global variable: it will keep the value from one call to the other
                        // but it has teh advantage of being seen only by your function
    if((GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_K) & 0x8000) && (ko == 0)){
        ko = 1;
        printf("Ok you pressed k");
        return 0;
    }
    else if((GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_K) == 0) && (ko == 1))  {
        ko = 0;
        printf("Now you released it");
        return 'K'; 
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void){
    bool go_on = true;   // The state of the loop shall be local variable not global
    while(go_on){
        Sleep(50);
        go_on= ! listentokb();  // if returns 0  we go on
    }
    return 0;
}
```